# Will c# form closing event work if the application is closed with task manager?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, taskmanager

I have a form with a form closing event, that event saves the last usage time of the application.

My question is 'Will the form closing event still work if the application is force closed with task manager'?

Comment: Take it to the extreme -- will it work if someone pulls the power plug? No, you can't rely on the event being called. In practice, it will probably be called if someone clicks "End Task", but not if they click "End Process"

Comment: Is there a work around for that?

Comment: No, nothing can stop someone terminating your process. You might want to periodically record the last usage time while the application is running as a backup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. The code located at your `FormClosing` event will never be executed when your application is killed by Task Manager.

But you could catch this event in other way. The task manager calls the Windows API `ExitProcess` to kill the process. You can check the [ProcessExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit?view=net-5.0) and [DomainUnload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.domainunload?view=net-5.0) events of the [AppDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) class.

For WinForms applications there's the `Application.ApplicationExit` event.

Maybe this document can also help you:

[How to know when the Task Manager kills your app.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20533/How-to-know-when-the-Task-Manager-kills-your-app)